# How to Make CSS Work on 404 Error Page?

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404

For some reason the CSS doesn't seem to be working on my error page [(here's an example of a broken link)](http://yogadetoxretreat.co.uk/images/pilates-retreat.png).

I have no idea why this might be, the code is exactly the same as the code calling the CSS file in the other .html documents.

Suggestions?

Thanks

Tara

Comment: Call me a standard nazi but an image url that should return an image returns an html document doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: @Kumar Which standard do you think is being violated, out of interest?

Comment: @matt, I really can not find such a document that would be called standard that says you should not serve html for urls that intend to serve image, looking at a URL, the intention seems to be to serve a PNG file but browser will see a html file. This can be replaced by serving an image that says image not found, not sure if there actually exists such a standard, but still, doesn't look good to me

Comment: @Kumar That image url is broken. It's supposed to be .jpg, but it's just an example of what's coming up with a 404 error when I have an image. The correct 404 page comes up when it's a broken .html doc.

Comment: @Tara, not sure, but I may have done with a 404 image for missing image files, 404 html document for missing html/text documents. I am not good at regex but can assure you that it can be done using some .htaccess + regex

Comment: @Tara, consider this use case, an image is pulled by some dyamic request in an img tag, some how image is not found, so img tag will recieve an html document instead of an image, if you serve image for an image you can take care of this situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The site cannot find the `style.css` file in the `images` folder

Change your markup to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: This '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />' is the code I have on the 404 page. It actually works when the broken link ends in .html

Comment: Not when its in the images folder though. Because its in a folder it cant pick up a stylesheet from the same folder, so you need to root the path.

Comment: Add the `/` to the `href` and test it out. Should fix it no problem.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't spot that there was a difference between /style.css and style.css. But I've tried it now and it works so thank you :)

Comment: The real issue is type="text/css" the media part is optional.

Answer (score 2):

You 404 page contains a 404 error! The file `/images/style.css` does not exist. On the rest of the website yo refer to `/styles.css` so may be that is the correct path.

Comment: Where does it show /images/style.css? I've even tried putting the 404 file in that folder to see if it would call it but it doesn't. This '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />' is the code I have on the 404 page. It actually works when the broken link ends in .html

Comment: @Tara: I cannot see the page at this moment. But it seems like you're using a template document for all pages whether they are in `/` directory or deeper. Simple add a `/` in the link to css file so that it becomes `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`; it should work as expected. Here is another page that has a similar error: http://yogadetoxretreat.co.uk/aaa/bbb/ccc

Comment: Thank you for the test link! Yes, I did as you suggested and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in .htpaccess doc

```
ErrorDocument 404 /usual-error-document.html
#
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png)$">
ErrorDocument 404 /404.gif
</FilesMatch>
```

and create .gif file to show 404 error.

[See here for more important details if you intend to edit this code...](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4101841.htm)